# What are the drawbacks of HQL and Criteria?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate's HQL does many operations as SQL but still what are the drawbacks of using HQL and Criteria.

Comment: drawbacks as compare to what? in what scenario?

Answer (score 0):

HQL queries cannot perform DDL operations.

HQL queries cannot insert single record into table.

An HQL query gives negligible performance degradation because of conversions when compared to SQL.

HQL queries cannot call PL/SQL program.

**NOTE : here i assumed to you are comparing with sql.**